# Решить задачу на php "Прямоугольник"

Tags: php

Вся суть в картинке.
Нужно написать функцию. 
Можно и на js.

[image: а]

Comment: 1) Подумать, как исходные данные связаны с ответом 2) Написать функцию  Какой пункт не получается?

Comment: Нужно - пишите. За Вас это никто делать не станет - тут не бюро добрых услуг. Будут проблемы с конкретным участком кода - приходите, спрашивайте, подскажем.

Comment: @MBo из исходных данных можно узнать только S. Предполагаю, что автору дали тестовое или олимпиаду какую-то)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну реально было сложновато.. (теорема Пика, если кому интересно)

---

```
/**
 * Side-horizontal * side-vertical + All-nodes - 1 = Rectanle Lines     (3 * 3 + 4 - 1 = 12)
 * Side-horizontal * side-vertical = Rectanle Lines + 1 - All-nodes     (3 * 3 = 12 + 1 - 4)
 * 
 * @param int $K | Nodes
 * @param int $N | Lines
 * 
 * @return array
 */
function getRectangleSize (int $K, int $N): array {
    $rectangleSize  = $N + 1 - $K;
    $rectangleSide = [];

    for ($side = 2; $side < $rectangleSize; $side++) {

        if (is_int ($rectangleSize / $side)) {
            $rectangleSide['first'] = $side;
            $rectangleSide['second'] = $rectangleSize / $side;

            if ($K == (($rectangleSide['first'] - 1) * ($rectangleSide['second'] - 1))) {
                return $rectangleSide;
            }
        }
    }
}

echo '<pre>';
var_dump (getRectangleSize (6, 17));
var_dump (getRectangleSize (8, 22));
var_dump (getRectangleSize (12, 31));
var_dump (getRectangleSize (14, 37));
```

---

Выход:

```
array(2) {
  ["first"]=>
  int(3)
  ["second"]=>
  int(4)
}

array(2) {
  ["first"]=>
  int(3)
  ["second"]=>
  int(5)
}

array(2) {
  ["first"]=>
  int(4)
  ["second"]=>
  int(5)
}

array(2) {
  ["first"]=>
  int(3)
  ["second"]=>
  int(8)
}
```

Comment: Не обязательно перебирать возможные стороны, можно решить квадратное уравнение.

Comment: @MBo Какое ради интереса? Решал сам, смог только так.

Comment: `K=(a-1)*(b-1); N=(a-1)*b+(b-1)*a.` Может быть, проще сначала найти произведение (у Вас уже есть) и сумму, потом из них стороны.

Comment: @MBo В Ваших уравнениях фигурируют неизвестные: a и b, представляющие стороны прямоугольника, вся соль, как из имеющихся данных K и N, программно их узнать?

Comment: Два уравнения - два неизвестных. Узнать - решением системы (сведётся ко квадратному уравнению)

Comment: `p=a*b; s=a+b; p-s=K-1; 2p-s=N; p=N-K+1; s=p-K+1; a^2-s*a+p=0;`